# How do I view linting errors when i run 'gulp'?

Tags: javascript, gulp, eslint, airbnb-js-styleguide, eslint-config-airbnb

I'm trying to install the Airbnb JavaScript style guide into my environment.  I'm using gulp to show linting errors as I save my .js files but it does not show it. If I do 'eslint main.js' it shows me the errors.

Is there any way I can show it through gulp when I execute 'gulp'?

Here are my config files:

```
var lint = require('gulp-eslint');  //Lint JS files, including JSX
var config = {
    port: 9005,
    devBaseUrl: 'http://localhost',
    paths: {
        html: './src/*.html',
        js: './src/**/.js',
        css: [
            'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
            'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'
        ],
        dist: './dist',
        mainJs: './src/main.js'
    }
};
```

...

```
gulp.task('lint', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.paths.js)
        .pipe(lint())
        .pipe(lint.format())
        .pipe(lint.failAfterError());
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(config.paths.html, ['html']);
    gulp.watch(config.paths.js, ['js', 'lint']);
    gulp.watch(config.paths.css, ['css']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['html', 'js', 'css', 'lint', 'open', 'watch']);
```

my main.js file:

```
test = 1;

var App = console.log('Testing Browserify');

module.exports = App;
```

and here is what I see when I run 'gulp' and also when I run 'eslint main.js'.  Errors should show on the terminal to the right, but it does not show any linting errors.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting your eslint configuration file on lint call?

```
gulp.task('lint', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.paths.js)
        .pipe(lint({
            // Load a specific ESLint config
            configFile: 'eslintConfig.json'
        }
    ))
    .pipe(lint.format())
    .pipe(lint.failAfterError());
});
```

From: https://github.com/adametry/gulp-eslint/blob/master/example/config.js